# How can I customize an iPhone first launch experience based on specific users?

Tags: iphone

I am trying to make my app automatically load specific content for a user upon the first launch.

For example, if a user is searching for information on product X via Safari, I would like to give them a referral to download my app in iTunes. After download, I would then like the app to automatically load screens relevant to product X without the user entering that info in themselves.

It seems that since apps are sandboxed they wouldn't have access to Safari cookies, as this would otherwise be the perfect solution.  Any advice?

Comment: I don't think that's possible...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Altough it's very interesting concept, I'm afraid **it's impossible**. The only idea that comes to my mind is to:

1. Store device's ID when user visits your website as well as what page was visited before redirecting to the AppStore.
2. Waiting for user to download the app.
3. Querying your server for this data on application launch and then setting up your UI accordingly.

However, the device ID is not exposed through Mobile Safari and even if you'd find a way to get it, this action would definetly be considered **illegal**.

Comment: I suppose the IP address could also be used - especially if the user is on a typical home WiFi, the IP could be fairly stable... But of course that isn't very reliable.

Comment: Thanks guys, this definitely gives me some thinking room. Could also pull in location data to start triangulating on this.

Comment: just out of curiosity / ignorance : what part of what you describe is considered illegal? Is it merely the act of storing the device ID on the server, or something else?

Comment: Perhaps using "illegal" is to strong, but it's a huge privacy issue. It would allow everyone to match your web activity with device, thus for instance enabling simple position tracking. It might not seem like a big deal, but the less private information is exposed the better. I personally believe it's good philosophy to let *user* decide which pieces of personal information to broadcast, and make it impossible for marketing agencies to leech data on demand.

Comment: Thanks. Doing this automatically might be tough. Another option we might have is to have the user enter their email address before downloading the app, and when they download the app and sign up we will know what they were last viewing.